Is it possible to see the request coming in to an SCDF Server?
An external service tries to start a SCDF Task with a Rest call. But I only see it's missing some properties it should have.
Is it possible to see the exact call that is coming in to the SCDF Server? I can't find it in the logs and I'm not sure if it should be there. I assume they are not correctly encoding the properties.
How the call should look like is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-launching
But without seeing the request on the server, it's difficult for me to help them.
I've tried to find the logs for the request on the SCDF Server and SCDF Skipper, but sadly didn't find anything.

You can set the following properties:
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=true
This should enable logging of requests and request parameters by the embedded Tomcat. The logs are sent to logs/access_log
The character in the sample request 'name=taskA&properties=app.my-task.foo%3Dbar%2Cdeployer.my-task.something-else%3D3&arguments=--server.port%3D8080+--foo%3Dbar' can be understood as follows:
name=taskA
properties=app.my-task.foo=bar,deployer.my-task.something-else=3
arguments="--server.port=8080 --foo=bar"

